# How to set the default folder for image uploads on teamsites

Tags: 2010, team-sites, image-upload

I am running a SharePoint 2010 installation. We have created team-sites which includes an image list. When users upload images, it would be nice if the default folder that the image loads into is the images folder for that team-site. Currently when the user uploads an image, the upload dialog box displays the wrong default folder. See image:

[image]

I have tried to find where I can set the default value but to no avail.

How do I make the images folder the default selection in the dialog box? I am looking for an out of the box solution preferably.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to set the Library name as default value or have your own Upload box. Check the below thread:

[Change the default file upload destination library in a discussion board post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162012/change-the-default-file-upload-destination-library-in-a-discussion-board-post)