# Change default 'Browse...' location when uploading to a SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-upload

I am working on a SharePoint site that is used in a process flow where one step requires the user to copy a document file from **one specific** Document Library (located in another SharePoint site) to another specific Document Library in my SharePoint site. I want to ensure that the user can easily achieve this without having to save the file to their local drive beforehand.

I am thinking that perhaps it would be a solution to modify the 'Upload' button of the Document Library so that the 'Browse...' location by default is the hyperlink to the desired Document Library.
Something like this:
[image]

Do you think this is a satisfactory solution - and if so, how can do I make this modification?

Please feel free to recommend other solutions to this problem.

Comment: Quick question. You say that your process requires the user to copy the file from one location to another. The result will be is you will have the same file in two locations. Does the document need to physically located in two locations? If you just want the document to be SEEN in a second location, would you consider "Link to a document" as a potential solution? It creates the appearance of another file but in fact it points back to the first file. This way if one user updates the source file, users accessing both file locations see the same content.

Comment: @KyleRogers-Brodeur The essence of the proces is that a user copies a checklist template document (that the quality manager ensures is up to date in a seperate Document Library) to the other Document Library, after which the user can resume to fill out the checklist. So therefore the link option can not be used for this purpose. Thanks for your response! Looking forward to hearing from you again

Comment: Perfect, just wanted to know. I proposed an answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the default upload location. An article on stack exchange explains it here.

[Change the default file upload destination library in a discussion board post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162012/change-the-default-file-upload-destination-library-in-a-discussion-board-post)

What you can do is navigate to the desired library, go to library settings. Click on advance settings.

Scrolls down and you will see this option: CUSTOM SEND TO DESTINATION.

[image]

Fill out the desired URL for your folder, and off you go.

Try that out and let me know if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because it's not always the same library that the user uploads to - each 'project' has a library of its own currently.